# A smart way to implement the same functions

Tags: android

I have a lot of views and have same function `postInvalidate()`.

```
regenerate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            img01.postInvalidate();
            img02.postInvalidate();
            img03.postInvalidate();
            img04.postInvalidate();
        }
});
```

Is there a better way to do this? This looks stupid.

Answer (score 1):

Put them in an array (or similar data structure) and iterate over that array calling `postInvalidate`?